# How to do case sensitive tags search in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, search, tags

How can I do a case-sensitive tags-search in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with normal search (with `C-s`) you probably want to set `tags-case-fold-search` instead of `case-fold-search`.  You can do what was mentioned:

```
(set-default 'tags-case-fold-search nil)
```

or using `M-x customize-variable <RET> tags-case-search-nil` and then change it to case-sensitive (0) by clicking on `Value menu`, and then saving it for future sessions (1) by clicking on State.

Answer (score 1):

Building on your answer, this is what you need:

```
(set-default case-fold-search nil)
```

which sets the default value, which will affect all buffers that haven't set the value locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the variable case-fold-search to nil, then all letters must match exactly, including case.

Correction to Trey Jackson's answer:

```
(set-default 'case-fold-search nil)
```

You need to quote the variable.

Comment: But this is only per buffer, need a global setting.